# How to make an MVC web application adjust to automatically fit different screen sizes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My MVC web application fits perfectly onto desktop monitors, which I've tried from 17" up to 22".  However when it was loaded onto a laptop screen, which was 14" or 15" some fields were pushed out of position making the web application untidy looking. I used

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

as I thought this would solve the issue but it hasn't. Is there a way of being able to display the application on laptop screens?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to edit the CSS for smaller screens using media queries. By doing this you can set certain CSS rules depending on the size of the screen. Example:

```
//for a mobile sized screen
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    //CSS for all screens under 300px
}
```

You can continue doing this for a few diferent screen sizes. you can also do styles for ranges of screen sizes. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 301px ) and (max-width 700px) {
    //CSS for all screen sizes between 301px and 700px
}
```

If you are using MVC though you should have Bootstrap installed in the project. If so have a look at how to use Bootstrap's column layout, its a powerful tool for creating responsive websites that look great on all screen sizes.

Comment: Great advice I'll give this a go and checkout the inbuilt Bootstrap

Comment: Do its a brilliant resource, you can set certain column sizes for large, medium, small and extra small screens. Theres a load of great styles pre-built into it that you can use for your site also.