# MVC Web form without database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, email

I'm in the process of refitting a website that I'd previously built using ASP.net with VB in the code-behind, into MVC with VB so that it's more responsive to different screen sizes and device types.

So far I've been able to replicate six of the pages plus the Site.Master files. Now I'm turning my attention to the Contact page which in asp.net takes data from a form, validates it for completion and data-type compliance and then passes it to the code-behind which uses it to generate an email.

I've done quite a lot of reading which suggests using a Model but all the examples I've found then use that Model to populate or query a database using LINQ.

How can I do this without a database?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve and how examples with a database access are affecting your solution.

Comment: With mvc, I have two methods (subs). One for the httpget, which shows the form that needs to be filled out by the user by passing a model of the info I need to process. One for the httppost, which receives the model with the info loaded. I can then use the model.info (individual fields) to process the data by creating an email using the model values.

Comment: It's hard to give specific help without code.

Comment: FYI : Simply changing your web forms app to MVC **will not** make your site responsive to different screen sizes!

Answer (score 0):

The M in MVC stands for Model, not Mdatabase.  You can use whatever you want as the model.  Most applications use a database and most .NET applications use EF to access a database (or at least Microsoft want it that way) but you can use whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using a database engine is recommended as permanent storage, but essentially you can create model class for contact page without involving a database like this:

```
public class Contact
{
     [Required]
     public String Name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use LINQ/lambda expressions after wrapping your model class into a collection (e.g. List), as example:

```
var list = new List<Contact>();
list.Add(new Contact { ... }); // adding items to the list 

// Lambda syntax
var name = list.Select(x => x.Name); // returns a value from the list

// LINQ syntax
var email = (from item in list 
             select item.EmailAddress);
```

Then you can convert the code-behind logic to a controller action method as `ActionResult` each for GET and POST request. Afterwards, `Redirect`, `RedirectToAction` or simply `return View()` after data submission can be used for page handling.

About responsive page design to work with different screen sizes and device types, MVC itself not designed to present responsive layouts by default. You need to alter some HTML & CSS-related attributes, as similar problem here:

[How to make an MVC web application adjust to automatically fit different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170395/how-to-make-an-mvc-web-application-adjust-to-automatically-fit-different-screen)

NB: Since your problem doesn't include any code, the provided codes are just examples as figure to what should be done.